# How does C# do type inference?

Tags: type-inference

Sometimes the C# compiler can do some type inference when you have to specify the generic parameters of some methods, like:

```
list.Select<[type of x.xx]>(x => x.xx)
```

Can be shorten as

```
list.Select(x => x.xx)
```

. This feature is quite unstable and confusing. Consider another example:

```
public interface ISome
{
  int Method(string arg);
}

public class Mock<T>
{
  public void Setup<TResult>(Func<T, TResult> func) { }
}

public static class It
{
  public static T IsAny<T>() { return default(T); }
}
```

And we wish we can write this:

```
var mockSome = new Mock<ISome>();
mockSome.Setup(s => s.Method(It.IsAny()));
```

But C# compiler will raise error in this case:

> The type arguments for method 'It.IsAny()' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

Since the type signature of `ISome.Method` is consistant, it's known at compile time. But the C# compiler asks you to specify the generic parameter of `It.IsAny`.
So we have to do this:

```
mockSome.Setup(s => s.Method(It.IsAny<string>()));
```

This is quite strange. Is there a way to formally, or, correctly and totally describe the C# compilers' type inference rule? (like, in what circumstances will C# compiler infer the type; in what circumstances won't?

Comment: A priori a question about C# seems off-topic here. For C++, type inference is probably described in the standard, but I'm not sure whether there are equivalent whitepapers for C#.

Comment: I put it here because it's related to type system, and it's varies in languages. Anyway thanks for your answer.

Comment: Apparently there is a public spec: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7029. It should contain the type inference algorithm (see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3697252/problem-understanding-c-sharp-type-inference-as-described-in-the-language-specif).

Comment: This seems to be C# specific, though. I tried the equivalent in Scala, and the type argument to `IsAny()` was inferred. Perhaps StackOverflow would be more appropriate than CS -- there are more C# experts there.